# Xamarin Forms. TCP Client. Реализация

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Возникла необходимость написать мобильное приложение (Android/iOS), на Xamarin Forms (опыта работы в принципе нет). Приложения должны коннектиться с серверу в wifi сети и обрабатывать tCP пакеты (знаю ip/port). Пакет представляет собой строку. Нужно чтобы приложение постоянно принимало/обрабатывыло строку (1 раз в секунду) и выводило на экран.
Можете подсказать какие компоненты использовать? Как правильно сделать Timer или нужно подписаться на событие?

UPD 1.0

```
    private async Task ConnServTCP() //
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        try
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(server, port); //соединение с сервером               
            StColor.Color = Color.Green; // установка цвета
            await GD(); // чтение данных                
        }
        catch
        {
            StColor.Color = Color.Red;
        }
    }    
    private async Task GD()
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[256];            
        while (true) // 
        {
            if (client.Connected) // проверяю если соединение есть
            {
                var v = client.GetStream(); // получил NetworkStream
                do
                {
                    int bytes = v.Read(data, 0, data.Length); // считал данные
                    LRData.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes); // у Label на форме поменял значение                        
                }
                while (v.DataAvailable); // до тех пор пока есть данные                   
                await Task.Delay(1000); //жду секунду        

            }
        }
    }
```

Также на форме предусмотрен Label на котором отображается время, которое постоянно раз 1 сек обновляется, сделал так:

```
    private async void DisplayTime()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ltime.Text= DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");                
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

Но получается если есть пакеты, время затармаживается. Либо я не понимаю как корректно работать в Xamarin с Async/или потоками.

**UPD2**
Убрал Task.Delay
Сделал так, в конструкторе объявил

```
    Timer t = new Timer(1000);
    t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
    t.Start();


    void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        ltime.Text= DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); 
    }
```

В отладке я вижу работу таймера, но Label не меняется...,подумал, почитал, решил реализовать INotify..

```
    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private new void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
            return;

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Объявил свойство

```
    private string _times;
    public string Times
    {
        get { return _times; }            
        set
        {
            _times = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Times");

        }
    }
```

В Xaml добавил

```
<Label Text="{Binding Times}"></Label> и так <Label Text="{Binding Path=Times}"></Label>
```

но Label так и не Биндит значения

Comment: TCP клиент не работает? это System.dll https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Добавил в описание вопроса. Получается что проблемы с коннектом нет. я вижу что клиент подключился к серверу, но при работе метода GD появляются странности. зависает, основная форма (вижу по работе метода  DisplayTime()). И вообще в принципе, на сколько корректно я получаю данные? При подключении к серверу, сервер посылает строку раз в 100 мс, мне нужно в другом потоке обрабатывать поступающие строки от сервера и выводить на экран

Comment: попытайтесь забыть Task.Delay и не замораживать поток. Есть таймер, у него установить время срабатывание и подпишитесь на это событие https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Ок, забыл, но все равно не получается. описал в UPD2

Comment: Почему вы ConnectAsync написать догадались, а Read используете простой?

Answer (score -1):

```
v.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Без try-catch...

Мда, сколько еще впереди - не позавидуешь.

Может, вместо TCP взять хоть что-то более готовое и высокоуровневое?

Comment: Может там соединение которое в жизни не упадёт да и вообще все написано без багов ;-)

Comment: Да не. Как это без try/catch? не понимаю...Просто нужно разобраться. А что можно взять готовое и высокоуровневое?

Comment: Как вы себе представляете соединение, которое в жизни не упадет? Дело не в багах. Есть роутер, есть кабель... Ничто не вечно. А уж в глобалнете вообще жесть. Кроме обрывов связи еще есть боты.

Comment: Я тоже не понимал, пока не провел эксперименты, намеренно вынимая роутер из розетки и наблюдая. В итоге все понял, умею писать надежные клиент-серверы на TCP, но все равно избегаю этого - слишком легко в каком-то месте чего-то не учесть, и там будет вылетать - раз в неделю, месяц - но вылетать.

Comment: "Что взять" - зависит от того, что можно взять на сервере вместо TCP и можно ли вообще. Как вариант - банально HTTP. На сервере поставить обычный апач с php, и до php по идее будут доходить только успешно отправленные запросы. Ну, проверить наличие всех параметров, если все есть - то ОК, если нет - exit() и все. На клиенте там тоже проще некуда - либо ок, либо не ок, и если ок, то break, а если нет, то снова слать запрос в бесконечном цикле.

Comment: На сервере есть только TCP/UDP. Причем на стороне клиента решен вопрос в пользу TCP